# django 1.3 templatestag if string contains list of strings

Tags: django

How can I check if a string is one of a list of values

```
('image_1', 'image_2'..etc)
```

How can check if a string equal to one of the values in the list? In python, an equavilant would be

```
if 'mystring' in ('yes' ,'no', 'mystring'):
  return True
```

how can i do the above using django templatetags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django templates come with the[`in` operator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#in-operator) as well.

```
{% if some_string in some_list %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```

This was first [introduced in django 1.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/releases/1.2/) as one of the operators supported by the ["smart" `if` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/releases/1.2/#new-in-1-2-smart-if).